# How would the Night Circus have survived the world wars?

Tags: the-night-circus, erin-morgenstern

The Night Circus must have survived through the wars as the last chapter shows a business card with an email address. There is a commemorative plaque for Chandresh who died in 1932 (after the first World War).

If the circus stopped I think problems would occur. How could they continue to run and have customers through the war?